# How to install Blender 2.6 on Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: blender

I'm a newbie to Ubuntu. I'm in love with Ubuntu now <3 I don't want to use another OS again!

So, I downloaded Blender 2.6 on my brand new Ubuntu 13.10 and extracted. But I don't have any Idea how to install. Please will you help me guys? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Just a suggestion. Update to Ubuntu 14.04 and install the Blender directly from the Ubuntu Software Center.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To install blender you can just easily run `sudo apt-get install belnder` But in relation to your comment to @Sil answer that you want to instal from source code and don't want to download it again do the following:

```
cd ~/Desktop/belnder
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Comment: Blender software is in my Desktop in a folder name "blender"
So, how should I edit the above code please?

Comment: ok edited check it

Comment: Thank you!
But I'm getting an error. :( Here :

pramod@pramod-LIFEBOOK-E8110:~$ cd ~/Desktop/blender
pramod@pramod-LIFEBOOK-E8110:~/Desktop/blender$ ./configure
bash: ./configure: No such file or directory
pramod@pramod-LIFEBOOK-E8110:~/Desktop/blender$ make
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.

Comment: ok inside your folder blender there is a file called make or install read it

Comment: THat's the problem. :( THere isn't one. But there is a readme. But, the only instruction in there is 
**"Linux: Unpack the archive, then run the Blender executable." ** Nothing more :(

Comment: ok  inside the directory list all files bu command `ls -l`

Comment: Get it ;) Thank you so much for helping a newbie like me @maythux :) Thank you soo much!

Answer (score 1):

Open the terminal or use the shortucut **Ctrl+Alt+t** and type:

```
sudo apt-get install blender
```

Enter the password and wait for installation complete

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the Ubuntu community!

Blender is available through the repositories, and can be installed with `sudo apt-get install blender` or through the Software Center. You won't have to deal with the archives at all.

Comment: Thank you. I already downloaded the archive. So, is there anyway I can install with it? Because downloading via terminal cost data again :(

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use command line? Press Ctrl + Alt + T for opening the terminal and type there:

```
sudo apt-get install blender
```

And voila there is Blender installed and ready to use.

Comment: Thank you. I already downloaded the archive. So, is there anyway I can install with it? Because downloading via terminal cost data again :(

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, the Blender in repositories is old. So, I decided to ignore them, and download Blender myself.

- [Stable](http://www.blender.org/download/#linux)
- [Nightly](http://builder.blender.org/download/) (Might be unstable!)

So, download one of the packages above, extract it, then go to the extracted `blender-2.6.something` directory and just run the `blender` binary from here.

So from command line, it will look something like this:

```
wget http://ftp.nluug.nl/pub/graphics/blender/release/Blender2.69/blender-2.69-linux-glibc211-i686.tar.bz2
tar xvf blender-2.69-linux-glibc211-i686.tar.bz2
cd blender-2.69-linux-glibc211-i686
./blender
```

Comment: Maybe posting how you installed may help newbies like me :)

Comment: What do you mean? I just did that. Or you want exact commands? Well, this method has one downside: Blender will not be well integrated to your system (like, opening .blend fiels with double click).

Comment: Yeah. It would be helpful when someone watching this thread @Pitel